# Convergence in the sense of distribution and weak convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, weak-convergence

A sequence of function $\{f_n\} \in L^p(\Omega)$ which converges in the sense of distribution need not be convergent in the weak topology of $L^p(\Omega)$. A classical example being a sequence of mollifiers converging to dirac delta distribution.

However, in addition suppose we know that the distributional limit is a function $f \in L^p(\Omega)$, can we conclude that $f_n$ converges to $f$ weakly in $L^p(\Omega)$?

A counter example or a clean proof is  greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

No. You need boundedness of the sequence. Take $f_n = \chi_{(0,1/n)} n^n$. Then $f_n$ converges to zero in the sense of distribution on $(0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks. I added a proof of the convergence when $f_n$ is bounded in $L^p$.

Answer (score 3):

In addition if $f_n$ is bounded in $L^p(\Omega),$ then the convergence follows as below:

We need to prove that for every $g\in L^q(\Omega)$, $\int_{\Omega}f_ng \rightarrow \int_{\Omega}f_ng.$

For a given $\epsilon >0$, consider
\begin{align}
& \left| \int_{\Omega}f_ng-\int_{\Omega}f g \right|\\
&\leq  \left| \int_{\Omega}  f_ng-f_n\phi+f_n\phi-f\phi+f\phi-f g \right|\\
& \leq \|f_n\|_{L^p(\Omega)} \|g-\phi\|_{L^q(\Omega)} + \left| \int_{\Omega}f_n\phi-\int_{\Omega}f\phi \right| + \|f\|_{L^p(\Omega)} \|\phi-g\|_{L^q(\Omega)}\\
&:=A_n+B_n+C_n
\end{align}
By the definition of $f_n \rightarrow f$   in $\mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$ there exists $N$ such that $B_n \leq \epsilon/3$ for all $n \geq N.$ $A_n$ and $C_n$ can be made sufficiently small using density of $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ in $L^q(\Omega)$. Finally since $\|f_n\|_{L^p(\Omega)} \leq K$ we can choose $\phi$ such that $A_n, B_n \leq \epsilon/3$.

Comment: Looks fine. You can combine $A_n$ and $C_n$ in one integral and then estimate them together.